# Free Drag with cdkDropList

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, drag-and-drop

I'm working on a project where I need to implement some sort of drop zone where you can drag element from a list, then drop them in a zone where they can be dragged freely. I also would like to use a cdkDropList for the zone, because it provides all the tools for connecting lists.
I used [this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d6xsgx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fexample%2Fexample.component.html) as a reference for my implementation, but I am not able to make it work right.

When I drop an item in the zone, it does not drop where the cursor was, it just goes to the top left of my zone, like it was in a list.

When I drag an item in the zone, it either drags correctly to where I want it to be dropped, gets dropped near the drop point, or just goes back to the top left.

**Here is my cdkDrag element**, it differs from the example linked above because I absolutely need it to be in it's own component (I would like to apply some logic to it in the future), but it is essentially the same concept (cdkDrag div in cdkDropList div). I managed to route all the needed events to the parent element (the zone) using Outputs.

```
<div class="element-box"
     cdkDrag
     cdkDragBoundary={{boundary_name}}
     (cdkDragDropped)="dragDroppedEventToParent($event)"
     (cdkDragStarted)="dragStartedEventToParent($event)"
     (cdkDragMoved)="dragMovedEventToParent($event)">
    {{object_name}}
    <div *cdkDragPlaceholder class="field-placeholder"></div>
</div>
```

Here is **the logic** for the drag element:

```
export class ElementBoxComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input () object_name: string;
  @Input () boundary_name: string;
  @Input () itemSelf: any;

  @Output () dragMovedEvent = new EventEmitter<CdkDragMove>();
  @Output () dragStartedEvent = new EventEmitter<CdkDragStart>();
  @Output () dragDroppedEvent = new EventEmitter<any>();

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  dragMovedEventToParent(event: CdkDragMove) {
    this.dragMovedEvent.emit(event);
  }

  dragStartedEventToParent(event: CdkDragStart){
    this.dragStartedEvent.emit(event);
  }

  dragDroppedEventToParent(event: CdkDragEnd){
    this.dragDroppedEvent.emit({event, "self": this.itemSelf});
  }
}
```

Here is my **drop zone element**, where I render the drag elements (you can see that I routed the Outputs to methods in my logic for the zone):

```
<div class="drop-container"
      #cdkBoard
      cdkDropList
      [id]="'cdkBoard'"
      [cdkDropListData]="itemsInBoard"
      [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="connectedTo"
      cdkDropListSortingDisabled="true"
      (cdkDropListDropped)="itemDropped($event)">
  <app-element-box *ngFor="let item of itemsInBoard; let i=index" 
                  object_name="{{item.name}}" 
                  boundary_name=".drop-container" 
                  itemSelf="{{item}}"
                  style="position:absolute; z-index:i" 
                  [style.top]="item.top" 
                  [style.left]="item.left"
                  (dragMovedEvent)="elementIsMoving($event)"
                  (dragStartedEvent)="startedDragging($event)"
                  (dragDroppedEvent)="stoppedDragging($event)"></app-element-box>
  
  <svg-container class="bin-container" containerId="bin-image-container" *ngIf="_binVisible" height=40>
    <svg-image class="bin-icon" [imageUrl]="BIN_ICON_URL" height=40 width=40></svg-image>
  </svg-container>
</div>
```

And here are the relevant methods in the TS file for my drop zone:

```
itemDropped(event: CdkDragDrop<any[]>) {
    if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
      moveItemInArray(this.itemsInBoard, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
    } else {
      copyArrayItem(
        event.previousContainer.data,
        event.container.data,
        event.previousIndex,
        event.currentIndex
      )
    }
}

changePosition(event: CdkDragDrop<any>, field) {
    const rectZone = this.dropZone.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();
    const rectElement = event.item.element.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();
    const top = rectElement.top + event.distance.y - rectZone.top;
    const left = rectElement.left + event.distance.x - rectZone.left;

    const out = (top < 0) || (left < 0) || (top > (rectZone.height - rectElement.height)) || (left > (rectZone.width - rectElement.width));
    if (!out) {
      event.item.element.nativeElement.style.top = top + 'px';
      event.item.element.nativeElement.style.left = left + 'px';
    } else {
      this.itemsInBoard = this.itemsInBoard.filter((x) => x != event.item);
    }
}
```

Again, the only differences are that my elements are encapsulated in their own components, and that the way I access the top and left style elements of the components are different (the code in the example did not work).
I know that the problem is the way I calculate the top and left variable, but I've been stuck on this for a week and cannot seem to find out what's wrong with it.

Here is a [short demonstrative video](https://youtu.be/ne-YRN5fYZY) if you want to better visualize what I am talking about.

Does anyone know what could be wrong with this ? I am open to any suggestions, thank you :)

Comment: can u replicate the problem into stackblitz?

Comment: You’re specifically using cdkDropList which creates a droppable list - so not free form. https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficut without a stackblitz know what is wrong

In [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2imxxu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) I made two ckd-list

One cdkDropList (todoList) it's a typical "list", the other one is a dropZone (doneList). My elements are in the way

```
{label:string,x:number,y:number,'z-index':number}
```

The cdkDrag in the dropZone is in the way

```
<div cdkDrag class="item-box" 
        [style.top.px]="item.y" 
        [style.left.px]="item.x" 
        [style.z-index]="item['z-index']"
>
```

I choose that the todoList is connected to the dropZone, but the dropZone is not connected to anything. When I mover the elements of the dropZone if it's move away this one, simply add to the list

We need get the doneList as ElementRef

```
  @ViewChild('doneList',{read:ElementRef,static:true}) dropZone:ElementRef;
```

And the neccesary functions

```
  drop(event: CdkDragDrop<any[]>) {
    if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
      moveItemInArray(event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
    } else {
      transferArrayItem(
        event.previousContainer.data,
        event.container.data,
        event.previousIndex,
        event.currentIndex,
      );
      event.item.data.y=(this._pointerPosition.y-this.dropZone.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().top)
      event.item.data.x=(this._pointerPosition.x-this.dropZone.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().left)
      this.changeZIndex(event.item.data)
    }
    this.posInside={source:null,x:0,y:0}
  }

  moved(event: CdkDragMove) {
    this._pointerPosition=event.pointerPosition;
  }

  changeZIndex(item:any)
  {
    this.done.forEach(x=>x['z-index']=(x==item?1:0))
  }
  changePosition(event:CdkDragDrop<any>,field)
  {
    const rectZone=this.dropZone.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect()
    const rectElement=event.item.element.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect()

    let y=+field.y+event.distance.y
    let x=+field.x+event.distance.x
    const out=y<0 || x<0 || (y>(rectZone.height-rectElement.height)) || (x>(rectZone.width-rectElement.width))
    
    if (!out)
    {
       field.y=y
       field.x=x
    }
    else{
      this.todo.push(field)
      this.done=this.done.filter(x=>x!=field)
    }
  }
```

The .html like

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div
    cdkDropList
    #todoList="cdkDropList"
    [cdkDropListData]="todo"
    [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[doneList]"
    class="example-list"
    (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)"
  >
    <div
      class="example-box"
      *ngFor="let item of todo"
      cdkDrag
      [cdkDragData]="item"
      (cdkDragMoved)="moved($event)"
    >
      {{ item.label }}
      <div *cdkDragPlaceholder class="field-placeholder"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div
    cdkDropList
    #doneList="cdkDropList"
    [cdkDropListData]="done"
    class="drag-zone"
    cdkDropListSortingDisabled="true"
    (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)"
  >
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of done">
      <div
        cdkDrag
        class="item-box"
        [style.top.px]="item.y"
        [style.left.px]="item.x"
        [style.z-index]="item['z-index']"
        (cdkDragStarted)="changeZIndex(item)"
        (cdkDragDropped)="changePosition($event, item)"
      >
        {{ item.label }}
        <div *cdkDragPlaceholder class="field-placeholder"></div>
      </div>
    </ng-container>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello Eliseo ! Thanks for the help, this is exactly what I needed to go forward. Also sorry for the delay, me and my team decided to move on and come back to this problem later, which is why I'm only thanking you now.
I have a last comment on what you proposed as a solution: when i replace the `transferArrayItem` in your code by a `copyArrayItem` (which is the behaviour I want), and I drag two of the same element in the zone, they stick together as if they were one object. I tried to modify their data in the array, but they always revert to the other object. Do you know why that happens ?